# "At the right time" vs "at a right time"

Tags: articles

Tell me please what is the difference between the following sentences.

> It is totally fine to add suplementary exercises to the main lifts. Just do it at **the** right time.
>
> It is totally fine to add suplementary exercises to the main lifts. Just do it at **a** right time.

I heard the latter in a podcast where two native speakers discussed strength training. I was totally confused because I thought that only the definite article could be used before words like *right*, or *wrong*. If the second one is also right, then what shade of meaning does it bear?

Comment: I assume you mean “a right time” not “a **the** right time”

Comment: Unless I'm missing a subtle difference in meaning between the phrasing in the last part of this question, you've already asked the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208876/at-the-right-time-or-at-a-right-time-in-context). Please consider deleting the question from one of the sites—or making the difference between them more obvious.

Comment: As I commented there,  the statement that **the** is always used before **right** is simply false: *There is **a right** time for everything*. Are you talking only about the *specific* construction in your question—or about a general rule?

Comment: I am talking about my sentence. I want to see the difference between the two.

Comment: The second example, "at a right time" is incorrect. Native speakers doing recordings like podcasts often make grammar mistakes, so I wouldn't assume it's correct because you heard it on a podcast. You could instead say "at a good time" or "at an appropriate time" if you wanted to indicate that multiple times would work, but that timing is still important.

Comment: Now I am even more confused. Some of you say it is wrong, and some it is right. Could you please provide me with arguments why it is right or wrong?

Comment: The idiom is _the right time_. Definite article has an affinity with absolute words like _right, correct, true_. Any use of indefinite article simply refers to a group of definites -- _There's a right time for everything_ means that one should wait for **the** right time, in every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems natural to always expect *the* rather than *a* before *right time*, because there often is only one right time for a particular thing. This, however, needn't always be so. Suppose that it is OK to do something either between 10 and 11 AM or between 2 and 3 PM, but that it would be wrong to do it at any other time of the day. Suppose, moreover that it needs to be done only once, and that it makes no difference whether it is done during the 10-11 or 2-3 timeslot; neither is better than the other. In that case, it would seem perfectly appropriate to instruct somebody to do it at '**a** right time'. In fact, in such a scenario, telling someone to do it at 'the right time' could be confusing, because it would make the person wonder whether there are some considerations that make one time better than the other, after all.

Answer (score -1):

This question is actually asking the difference between the word "the" and the word "a"

The difference between "the" and "a" is the number

"the" says there is only 1
"a" says there is more than 1, and any one will do

this is a constant rule and it doesn't matter what is being discussed

> "the car" vs "a car"
> "the cat with the torn ear" vs "a cat with a torn
> ear"

now for the dictionary bit:

> "the"
> 1.1 Used to refer to a person, place, or thing that is unique.
> ‘the Queen’ ‘the Mona Lisa’ ‘the Nile’

both are from oxford dictionaries

> "a"
> 2. Used to indicate membership of a class of people or things.
>
> ‘he is a lawyer’
> ‘this car is a BMW’

Comment: I think the question is more specific than that.  It asks about “a right time” vs “the right time” noting that a rule he is aware of says “only ***the*** can come before *right*”.

Comment: @Jim maybe you are right.